# Nginx log request and response API Proxy

Tags: nginx

I have a configuration to redirect all my local API calls (from a client, with a apikey header) at `example.com` to a remote API server `distant-api-server.com:8000`).

```
upstream api-server {
    server distant-api-server.com:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html;
    server_name example.com;

    location ~ /api/(?<path>.*) {                                               

    if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {                                       
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";            
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';     
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'apikey';                 
        return 200;                                                         
    }                                                                       

    if ($api_route = "error"){return 501;}                                  

        error_page 501 /501_apikey.html;                                    

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'apikey';
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                            
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;                                
        proxy_pass http://$api_route/$path$is_args$args;                    
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;                      
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;                     
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;                                        
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;                                   
        proxy_redirect off;                                                 
    }
}
```

I'd like to log:
 - Request send from local server to /api
 - Request as sent then by Nginx to `http://$api_route/$path$is_args$args`
 - Response received from distant API and transmitted by Nginx to my client page

For the moment when I make calls to /api, an error on the distant API and then my request time out. By knowing what is sent/received by Nginx would help me debug.

How can I achieve that kind of logging?

Comment: https://nginx.org/r/access_log

Comment: the access log itself doesn't give me detailed http request and responses with headers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OP, Welcome to Server Fault!  As an FYI, listen to @MichaelHampton’s advice and triple check your instincts.  In this case the access log **really does** provide you with the information you likely want.  You just have to **tell it** what it is that you want logged.

To expand on M Hampton’s suggestion, what you should do is define your own log format for upstream/proxy logging and then add the `access_log` directive to the location from which you are doing `proxy_pass` using your custom log format.

```
location ~ /api/(?<path>.*) {
    log_format upstream_logging . . .;
    . . .
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api_logging.log upstream_logging;
}
```

And you can include whatever variables from nginx you want to in your log format.  You will have to specify which headers you want individually from the upstream [using the variables here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_header_time), for example `$upstream_http_server`.  Here is one proposed logging format for logging upstream information that you can use as a starting point.

```
log_format upstream_logging '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name to: $upstream_addr: $request upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time';
```

A little bit of googling and reading the docs (and listening to M Hampton!) will take you a long way.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, and Thanks to M. Hampton! I didn't know all the variables were accessible directly in a log_format. I created this on: `log_format upstream_logging '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name to: $upstream_addr: $request with $http_apikey <$request_body_file> --> upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time --- $sent_http_clientapikey ';` Do you have any idea on how to log response body? I didn't find the equivalent of request_body_file coupled with `client_body_in_file_only on`

Comment: I found multiple ressources about response body using lua which is not available on our server. I'm also wondering if there is any way to retrieve the upstream URL to which Nginx pass the request.

Comment: I think you might be looking for `$upstream_addr$request_uri` for the upstream URL.

Comment: Also, w/r/t lua, you should be able to build it separately and then load it dynamically per the installation instructions https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#building-as-a-dynamic-module.  What OS (flavor of linux) are you running nginx on?

Comment: Thanks for advices. We managed to get lua working and get all uri/body etc. But we ran to another problem: display in log the custo proxy header passed to upstream server and set with `proxy_set_header clientapikey $clientapikey;`. I opened another separate question for this one: http://serverfault.com/questions/824388/nginx-log-proxy-passed-custom-header

Comment: This doesn't log the upstream uri

Comment: Well, yeah, that's because at `proxy_pass` time, you always know what the upstream uri will be for any given `$request_uri`.