# Nginx log proxy_passed custom header

Tags: nginx

In my location, I set this code:

```
set $clientapikey "<my client api key>";

add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT';

proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                            
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;                                
proxy_pass http://$api_route/$path$is_args$args;                    
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;                      
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr; 
proxy_set_header clientapikey $clientapikey;                    
proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;                                        
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;                                   
proxy_redirect off;
```

I want to log the header sent by proxy_pass to the remote url to see if my key is actually sent to the distant server (`$api_route`).

I tried to log:

```
log_format 'Sent-Headers: "clientapikey: '
           '$upstream_http_clientapikey '
           '$http_clientapikey" ';
```

But nor $upstream_http_clientapikey nor $http_clientapikey seems to give me access to the proper sent header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only [thing you can do](https://marc.info/?l=nginx&m=147264065905324&w=2) is to just log `$clientapikey`.  But that will have a well-known value, so I don’t expect it to be of too much use to you in debugging this issue.  In this case, I would double check the API server header format using curl first on the nginx server.  My bet would be that the API server is actually expecting the HTTP Auth header.

```
curl -v -h 'clientapikey: my client api key' -X POST http://apiendpoint
```

n.b. As an aside, calling the api endpoint with `http://` should be discouraged because it would allow anyone to read your client api key.

Comment: We will be using https in the future. We are just starting our project :)